# K&R section 1.9

Tags: c, eof

I am working through Ritchie's and Kernighan's The C programming language, and I don't understand how the following code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main()
{
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;
    while((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0)
        printf("%s", longest);
    return(0);
}

int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c = getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return(i);
}

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

In the code ABOVE 
The getline() function returns value of i

and the while loop in the main runs till the time getline returns a positive value of i.

so how does the while loop terminates when EOF is encountered in the getline() function?

Comment: Note that condition is `> 0` and `i` may be `== 0`, that's when loop breks...

Comment: `getline()` has a weakness.  What is the point of `if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
    }`?, the next line `s[i] = '\0';` overwrite `s[i]`.  BTW, do not only replace with `s[i++] = c;`, that makes another problem (potential buffer overrun)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put:

if `EOF` is encountered, then `getline` returns whatever it has read up to the `EOF`.

In any next call of `getline()` it reads `EOF` again and so will return zero.

Comment: so when the first EOF is encountered current string is returned. and while loop is executed. During the next iteration since EOF occurred earlier current value of C is again EOF and getline() returns 0, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

The while loop terminates as the condition is false (once EOF has been encountered all further getchar requests also return EOF)

Answer (score 0):

Let's look the `getline()` function.

We have a *for* cycle which initialize the `i` to 0. Then, a condition is checked. One of the 3 conditions is `(c = getchar())!=EOF`.

So, if EOF is inserted, the for body isn't executed.

If `EOF` has been the first inserted char, the `i` is still `0`, so the `getline()` function returns 0.

If `EOF` isn't the first inserted character, the code continues to run and doesn't end the cycle in the main because `i` became > 0.

The check on the while in the `main()` is `while((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)`, so while the return value is **strictly** > 0.

`if (0 > 0) printf("true"); else printf("false");` prints `false` in C (and in every language I'm aware of).

Therefore the while body isn't executed, and the cycle ends.